# How to select last row in Office Scripts?

Tags: javascript, office-scripts

Good day,

I do not have any Java script knowledge, so what I am trying to solve will probably be very easy.

What I am trying to do in Excel, is to automate copying rows from a table from one area in a worksheet and insert it into another table in a different area in the same worksheet.

To do this, I have recorded the steps to automate this process using Office Scripts. Below is the script from the recording:

[image]

But what I would like to do, is to select the last row that contains data instead of a fixed row that might or might not have data.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's preferable to post your code in text format and use the markdown syntax to format it as code rather than posting an image of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Append data rows at the end

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // modify source and dest. table name as needed
    let tableSrc = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    let tableDes = workbook.getTable("Table2");
    // locate the first blank cell in the first col of dest table
    let anchorCell = tableDes.getRange().getColumn(0).getLastCell().getOffsetRange(1,0);
    // copy data rows from source table to dest table
    anchorCell.copyFrom(tableSrc.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal(), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
}
```

[image]

---

Insert data rows at the beginning

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // modify source and dest. table name as needed
    let tableSrc = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    let rowCount = tableSrc.getRowCount();
    let tableDes = workbook.getTable("Table2");
    // Insert row ainto dest table
    for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        tableDes.addRow(0);
    }
    // locate the first cell in the first col
    let anchorCell = tableDes.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getCell(0,0);
    // copy data rows from source table to dest table
    anchorCell.copyFrom(tableSrc.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal(), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> Question: However empty rows in the table are also copied across. How do you select only the rows in the source table that contain data?

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // modify source and dest. table name as needed
    let tableSrc = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    let lastCell = tableSrc.getRange().getColumn(0).getLastCell();
    if (lastCell.getText().length === 0) {
        lastCell = lastCell.getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up);
    }
    let endRow = lastCell.getRowIndex();
    let startRow = tableSrc.getRange().getRowIndex() + 1;
    if (endRow >= startRow) {
        let colCount = tableSrc.getRange().getColumnCount();
        let rowCount = endRow - startRow + 1;
        console.log(rowCount)
        let srcRange = tableSrc.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getAbsoluteResizedRange(rowCount, colCount);
        let tableDes = workbook.getTable("Table2");
        // Insert row ainto dest table
        for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            tableDes.addRow(0);
        }
        // locate the first cell in the first col
        let anchorCell = tableDes.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getCell(0, 0);
        // copy data rows from source table to dest table
        anchorCell.copyFrom(srcRange, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks taller for your answers and scripts. I have used the script you provided to insert rows at the beginning of a table and got the following error:
Line 5: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRowCount')
Is there a way to solve this error?

Comment: Have you changed the table name `Table1`?

Comment: I named my tables the same as yours (table1 and table2, for the source & destination tables respectively). I got the error msg. Then I tried to use other table names (InputTable & ArchiveTable) and changed accordingly in the script. Same error

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `named my tables`. Did you create it via Create>Table or Home > Format as Table? I guess you created a named range instead a table. `Microsoft documentation:`

> [Create and format tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: yes, I created a named range thinking it would be the same as a table.... I will create a table this time and re-run the script.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: that's great! it worked without copying across the empty rows. Thank you very much for all your help. Very much appreciated.